# Error in extracting a GZIP file using 7zip

Tags: xml, github, compression, gzip, 7zip

I am trying to extract a file named as "note.xml.gz" using 7zip 22.00 but I am getting an error saying

```
Open ERROR: Cannot open the file as [gzip] archive
```

I have downloaded the file from my remote git repository

Comment: There are different versions of the ZIP specification with optional features.  One tool may not work with another tool.  Also the disk where zip was create (sectors and cylinders) and extracted have to be compatible.  Moving a zip from one disk to another may not extract correctly.  Seen these type issues plenty of times over the years.  Usually happens when files are added to a zip after they the zip was originally created.

Comment: @jdweng You are confusing the zip format with the gzip format. A `.gz` file is _not_ a zip file. It is not an archive. It does not contain multiple files. It has only one compression format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is corrupted, or it is not a gzip file despite the `.gz` suffix. The latter can occur when you download with some browsers, where `note.xml.gz` may already have been decompressed in the process of downloading.

Have you looked at `note.xml.gz` at all? Does it look like XML? If not, are the first few bytes a gzip header? gzip files always start with 1f 8b 08 in hex.

Comment: Although this answer has been accepted, it isn't exact for all use cases. 7Zip refuses to open my `.sql.gz` DB dump, but Windows' Explorer is more than fine with it

Comment: @Vivick Can you provide a link to that file?